# multi-page TIFF to NRRD

Tags: python, image-processing, tiff

I have a multi-page 3D tiff image (ie a stack of tiffs) of type `uint16` and LZW compressed. I would like to convert the stack to the `nrrd` format, preferably in Python.
Does anyone how this is done please? Which tools are appropriate for something like this

Comment: Try [pynrrd](https://pypi.org/project/pynrrd/) and [tifffile](https://pypi.org/project/tifffile/): `nrrd.write(filename+'.nrrd', tifffile.imread(filename))`

Answer (score 0):

Check the Insight Toolkit (ITK) they have Convert3d function that could help you.
the below link is the manual of the mentioned function.
https://sourceforge.net/p/c3d/git/ci/master/tree/doc/c3d.md

Comment: If you cann share some sample code, that would be helpful

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).